# Change of coefficients and cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be nice space (not necessarily manifold). Say, (of top of my head) locally compact $T_2$, locally contractible.

Then, does the following hold?

Assume for some $k$, $H^{k}(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$ then does it follow that $H^k(X,\mathbb{R})=0$. What about the converse?

Example: Assume $X= \mathbb{R}P^n$ then yes, for $k>n$. But here $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is a compact manifold. So I was wondering if something more general holds.

Observation: UCT tells us $H_k(X,\mathbb{R})\cong H_k(X)\otimes \mathbb{R}$  So, if $H_k(X)=0$ then $H_k(X,\mathbb{R})=0$. Conversely, if $H_k(X,\mathbb{R})=0$ then $H_k(X)\otimes \mathbb{R}=0$, but this imply that $H_k(X)=0$?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that for every "nice" (what 's that?) $X$ there exists $k$ such that $H^k(X)=H^k(X; {\mathbb R})=0$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I edited.

Comment: For example, $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{R}$ is $0$ because $1\otimes r=2\otimes r/2=0\otimes r/2=0$. So, if $H^i(X,\mathbb{R})=0$ it is still possible for $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z})$ to have torsions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Do you know a version that doesn't have a finite-type assumption? The only statement I know is the one in Spanier (Theorem $5.5.10$) which requires either that either $H^*$ is of finite type, or that the new coefficient group is finitely generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither implication holds in general.

1. $H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}) = 0 \not\Rightarrow H^k(X; \mathbb{R}) = 0$.

Let $X$ be a manifold with $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Q}$; see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/192230/21564) for examples of such manifolds.

It follows from the Universal Coefficient for Cohomology that $H^1(X; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X;\mathbb{Z}), G)$ for any abelian group $G$. Note that $H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \pi_1(X)^{\text{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Q}^{\text{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Q}$, so $H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ while $H^1(X; \mathbb{R}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R} \neq 0$.

If $H^i(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated for every $i$, then $H^k(X; \mathbb{R}) \cong H^k(X;\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{R}$, in which case the implication does hold. See Theorem $5.5.10$ of Spanier's *Algebraic Topology* - note, Spanier uses the notation $A\ast B$ to denote $\operatorname{Tor}(A, B)$ which will vanish for this application.

2. $H^k(X; \mathbb{R}) = 0 \not\Rightarrow H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

This implication is much easier to construct counterexamples for. This is because $H^k(X; \mathbb{R})$ does not detect torsion, while $H^k(X; \mathbb{Z})$ does. For example, note that $H^2(\mathbb{RP}^2; \mathbb{R}) = 0$, while $H^2(\mathbb{RP}^2; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: Thank u. Very interesting @Michael Albanese. Im trying to understand this better by thinking of examples and contexts. so Two questions (1).  What if I modified my question to 'for all large k'?  (2). What if $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a retract of an open set $U$. Then, $H^i(K,\mathbb{Z})$ is f.g.? (deformation retract is clear since $H^i(K)=H^i(U)$ then.)

Comment: Thinking about my previous question more, in case $K$ is compact and retract of open set, then $K$ is a retract of a CW complex. So, I guess question can be phrased in compact case as: cohomology groups of retract of CW complexes finitely generated?

Comment: If $K$ is compact and a retract of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the homology groups (and hence cohomology groups) are finitely generated. See Corollary $A.8$ of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese What if K is non compact?

Comment: As Mariano pointed out, every manifold (compact or not) is a retract of an open set in Euclidean space, and if the manifold is non-compact, its cohomology need not be finitely generated.